How to change the function app local port in VSCode from 7071
I want to run two function app projects in two separate VSCode instances but they both use port 7071 and there doesn't appear to be a way to change it in launch.json.

port 7071 is unavailable. Close the process using that port, or
specify another port using --port [-p]

Is there a way to change the port to allow both VSCode projects to run at the same time locally? One will POST to the other.

This is how to change the local port in local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "...",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    ...
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7072
  }
}

